# ¿Cómo puedo cargar los datos de un json en una estructura similar a una tabla con KO?

Tags: javascript, html, json, knockoutjs

Quisiera generar el *binding* en [knockoutjs](/questions/tagged/knockoutjs) para una estructura tipo tabla como esta:

[image: tablero]

pero con las posiciones aleatorias. Para ello generé un [json](/questions/tagged/json) que refleja mi modelo de datos a como deseo que aparezca (debido a que como se verá abajo no pude hacer el binding desde el modelo):

```
{"filas":[{"columnas":[{"fichas":[{"clase":"col ","NumeroLetraSimbolo":["11"]}]},{"fichas":[{"clase":"col ","NumeroLetraSimbolo":["3"]}]},{"fichas":[{"clase":"col ","NumeroLetraSimbolo":["15"]}]},{"fichas":[{"clase":"col ","NumeroLetraSimbolo":["8"]}]}]},{"columnas":[{"fichas":[{"clase":"col ","NumeroLetraSimbolo":["1"]}]},{"fichas":[{"clase":"col ","NumeroLetraSimbolo":["10"]}]},{"fichas":[{"clase":"col ","NumeroLetraSimbolo":["5"]}]},{"fichas":[{"clase":"col vacio","NumeroLetraSimbolo":[""]}]}]},{"columnas":[{"fichas":[{"clase":"col ","NumeroLetraSimbolo":["7"]}]},{"fichas":[{"clase":"col ","NumeroLetraSimbolo":["9"]}]},{"fichas":[{"clase":"col ","NumeroLetraSimbolo":["13"]}]},{"fichas":[{"clase":"col ","NumeroLetraSimbolo":["12"]}]}]},{"columnas":[{"fichas":[{"clase":"col ","NumeroLetraSimbolo":["4"]}]},{"fichas":[{"clase":"col ","NumeroLetraSimbolo":["14"]}]},{"fichas":[{"clase":"col ","NumeroLetraSimbolo":["6"]}]},{"fichas":[{"clase":"col ","NumeroLetraSimbolo":["2"]}]}]}],"posiciones_tablero":[],"imagenDeFondo":[]}
```

De momento he intentado asignarlo así:

```
<div class="row tabla"  id="tabla1" data-bind="foreach: filas">
  <div data-bind="foreach: columnas">
   <div class="col" posicion="0" id="p1" data-bind="foreach:$parent.fichas">
    <p data-bind="text:$parent.NumeroLetraSimbolo"></p>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

El código ideal a generar es algo así:

```
<div class="row tabla" id="tabla1">
                <div class="col" posicion="0" id="p1" ng-click="mensaje($event)">1</div>
                <div class="col" posicion="1" id="p2" ng-click="mensaje($event)">2</div>
                <div class="col" posicion="2" id="p3" ng-click="mensaje($event)">3</div>
                <div class="col" posicion="3" id="p4" ng-click="mensaje($event)">4</div>
            </div> 
            <div class="row tabla" id="tabla2">
                <div class="col" posicion="0" id="p5" ng-click="mensaje($event)">5</div>
                <div class="col" posicion="1" id="p6" ng-click="mensaje($event)">6</div>
                <div class="col" posicion="2" id="p7" ng-click="mensaje($event)">7</div>
                <div class="col" posicion="3" id="p8" ng-click="mensaje($event)">8</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row tabla" id="tabla3">
                <div class="col" posicion="0" id="p9" ng-click="mensaje($event)">9</div>
                <div class="col" posicion="1" id="p10" ng-click="mensaje($event)">10</div>
                <div class="col" posicion="2" id="p11" ng-click="mensaje($event)">11</div>
                <div class="col" posicion="3" id="p12" ng-click="mensaje($event)">12</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row tabla" id="tabla4"> 
                <div class="col" posicion="0" id="p13" ng-click="mensaje($event)">13</div>
                <div class="col" posicion="1" id="p14" ng-click="mensaje($event)">14</div>
                <div class="col" posicion="2" id="p15" ng-click="mensaje($event)">15</div>
                <div class="col vacio" posicion="3" id="p16" ng-click="mensaje($event)"></div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que estas un poco confundido con la estructura del objeto, te recomiendo siempre analizar bien primero quien es el padre y quienes son los hijos porque veo algo cruzado ahi las propiedades, el resto es saber jugar con los indices.

Te dejo un fiddle de ejemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/LuisZ/dr8c1ank/3/

Lo ideal seria hacer tu propio custom binding, y mover toda esa logica a js en vez de html porque se mira un poco sucio pero ya te das una idea como tiene que ser

Comment: Gracias, curioso que no corriera en firefox y en los demás navegadores sí. Saludos.